# Sylius on Heroku, getting "phpcr_workspaces" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, symfony, heroku, sylius, doctrine-phpcr

I'm trying to install Sylius on Heroku. Here's what I do (taken from https://www.christophh.net/2013/10/19/sylius-on-heroku/):

1. Create a Heroku app, add a Postgres db
2. `composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard myAppName`
3. Push my app to Heroku
4. `heroku run php -d memory_limit=-1 app/console
   sylius:install`

During installation I am using db created in step 1, so I answer `N` to

> It appears that your database already exists. Would you like to reset it?

My installation crashes with:

> [PHPCR\RepositoryException]   Unexpected error talking to the backend:
>   An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT 1 FROM phpcr_workspaces
>   WHERE name = ?' with params ["default"]   :   SQLSTATE[42P01]:
>   Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "phpcr_workspaces" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM phpcr_workspaces WHERE name = $1

It seems that somewhere the script expects `phpcr_workspaces` table to be present, but there is none. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118943/6519983

Basically I need to initialize doctrine tables and workspace manually:

```
heroku run "php app/console doctrine:phpcr:init:dbal --force"
heroku run "php app/console doctrine:phpcr:workspace:create default"
heroku run "php app/console doctrine:phpcr:repository:init"
heroku run "php app/console -v -n doctrine:phpcr:fixtures:load"
```

Note: To continue with Sylius installation I also had to create Sylius tables as well:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```